# How to create type for api response with fields name starting with number?

Tags: javascript, typescript, rest

I have a api response like this

```json
{
  "randomField": "data",
  "3withNumber": "data"
}
```

I want to create a type for it.

```js
type ApiResponse {
    randomField: string,
    3withNumber: string
}
```

But as we cannot start the member name with a number. How can we handle this case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
type ApiResponse = {
  randomField: string,
  '3withNumber': string
}
```